# Why is RefreshDatabase seem to be required when unit testing Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6

I am using Laravel Passport to build an API for my Vue application. I am able to send `POST` request via browser and Postman without any issues.

I am (learning) about writing unit tests and would like to test my `store` method.

Here is what my sample test looks like:

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_create_a_thing()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $thing = factory(Thing::class)->raw();

    $response = $this->post('api/v1/thing', $thing);

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('things', $thing);
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'foo' => 'nullable',
        'bar' => 'required',
        'baz' => 'required',
    ]);

    $thing = Thing::create($attributes);

    return response()->json(['data' => $thing], 200);
}
```

I'm not checking/setting any authentication at this point (yet). Maybe that's where I'm going wrong.

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::post('thing', 'Api\v1\ThingController@store');
});
```

If I use `dd($thing)` I can see that everything is getting generated correctly and my controller is picking everything up as expected.

The error I get back is:

> Expected status code 200 but received 500.
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

In Postman, If I send a `POST` request to the same controller: `http://mysite.local/api/v1/thing`

Everything works great.

If I add `RefreshDatabase` my test passes. I don't understand why.

I've looked at the docs and added:

```
...
Passport::actingAsClient(
    factory(Client::class)->create(),
    ['check-status']
);
...
```

I get other additional errors using that. I've found [a post on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/test-fails-always-500-where-200-expected) that suggested setting `RefreshDatabase`. What that *does* seem to make the test pass, I don't feel super great about it.

How can I be sure my test(s) will work? I feel like this is a really basic test. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Erm... what is the error behind the 500 http error? check the log or where you store your errors?

Bonus what is you testing database strategy, seperate db with transactions, refresh or sqlite?